# How does rounding work when converting from integers to IEEE 754 floating point numbers?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, precision, ieee-754

There are many values that can be represented precisely as a 64-bit `long` but not as a 64-bit `double`. (A trivial example: 2<sup>62</sup>-1.)  Is the rounding away from zero, towards zero, or to nearest possible value given the spacing?

Comment: The rounding mode can be set with the `fesetround()` function.

Comment: `2^62` can be represented exactly as a double.

Comment: Yeah, a simple example of a long not precisely representable as a double is 2⁶²-1.

Answer (score 6):

Floating point semantics matching IEC 60559 (IEEE 754) are defined in Annex F of the standard, which technically is optional, but without which C's floating point is so underspecified as to be meaningless. Assuming Annex F, which specifies (F.3 ¶1):

> The conversions from integer to floating types provide the IEC 60559 conversions from integer to floating point.

Rounding takes place according to the currently active rounding mode. Rounding mode can be set by `fesetround` from `fenv.h`, but many compilers do not properly support fenv functionality and erroneously allow operations to be reordered across mode changes, so in practice you should probably leave it at the default (nearest/to-even).

In the absence of Annex F, conversion from integers is one of the few floating point operations that C specifies with any concreteness (6.3.1.4 ¶2):

> If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.

Annex F constrains the implementation-defined choice to agree with IEC 60559. Pretty much all real-world C implementations target Annex F, even if they don't conform to it 100%. Thus my own answers, and answers by a number of users on this site, generally assume that questions about C and floating point are treating Annex F as baseline.

Comment: Common C implementations follow the floating-point rounding mode and have that default to round-to-nearest, ties-to-even, but the C standard does not seem to require either of these, per [chqrlie’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63679430/298225).

Comment: Annex F does. Without Annex F, floating point semantics are so underspecified they can literally be random.

Comment: Annex F is not obligatory. Wishing the behavior to be well specified does not make it so. chqrlie’s answer is correct. This one is incorrect.

Comment: Many of us consider Annex F a core part of the language, as (1) it's impossible to do anything meaningful with floating point without at least a large subset of it, and (2) pretty much all real-world implementations target it, even if they don't conform 100%.

Comment: Re “Many of us consider”: Wishing does not make it so. It is not an obligatory part of the language. This answer is wrong. You could at least qualify the claim that rounding takes place as depending on Annex F. Then, at least, the answer would contain correct statements, although it would still be incomplete, as it would not answer OP’s unqualified question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Updated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Just noticed too that the question is tagged `ieee-754`...

Answer (score 3):

The behavior seems to be implementation defined. Here is the relevant paragraph of the C Standard:

> **6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer**
>
> When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.
> If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined. Results of some implicit conversions may be represented in greater range and precision than that required by the new type (see 6.3.1.8 and 6.8.6.4).

Comment: Annex F fills in the definition, though.